# problem with pnp search result V4 error 500

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sharepoint-search, pnp-search-webparts, sharepoint-page

i am on sharepoint online and i downloaded and used pnp search result V4 last week and it worked .

Since 2 days it didn't work anymore and i got a Error 500 each time i try to used it and to put it on a page. i don't understand why i didn't touched anything.

To reproduce that i created a new page and put the pnp search result and i still got the error 500 and the web part location ,i try on firefox and chrome[image: here is the picture of my page now].

Do you have any idea?

Comment: HTTP 500s are server-side errors and will need to be t-shot by Microsoft. Open a support case on https://admin.microsoft.com. It should be no cost to you (just your time... possibly soul).

Comment: @TrevorSeward Maybe a problem of right because now with administrator right i can do it again seems ive lost them this week. i will write to microsoft to know whats hapenned exactly thanks to the correlation id. thanks

Comment: i opened a support case on Microsoft they called me and told me that i couldn't do nothing about it ,it was a bug and then they fixed it on their side. End of the story thanks